# Count occurrences data from 2 columns using python

Tags: python, dataframe

In my forum.csv file, there are student_id and course_id columns. The data for that columns look like below:

```
student_id,course_id
886652,SIM4207
886652,SIM4207
4484596,SSE3306
4484596,SSE3306
5843448,SSE3150
886652,SIM4207
```

What I want to do is, I want to count the  occurrences for these 2 columns
for example

```
student_id,course_id, occurrences
886652,SIM4207- 1
886652,SIM4207- 2
4484596,SSE3306- 1
4484596,SSE3306- 2
5843448,SSE3150- 1
886652,SSE3150- 1
```

the occurrences need to save in a data frame because I need to visualise that data. This is the code that I did, but Im not sure how to put in dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv (r'forum.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['course_id','student_id'])
studentcourse = list(zip(df['course_id'], df['student_id']))
a= pd.Series(studentcourse).value_counts()
print(a)
```

anyone can help me to solve this?

my expected output is:

```
student_id,course_id, occurrences
886652,SIM4207, 2
4484596,SSE3306, 2
5843448,SSE3150, 1
886652,SSE3150, 1
```

means show the total amount for each pair (student_id, and course_id)

Comment: Could you please post your expected output?

Comment: Thank you, eidted my answer for the expected output. I hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to return the cumulative amount of repetitions that both values in columns `student_id` and `course_id` occur, you can solve it with a `groupby()`, `transform()` with the function `cumcount`:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['student_id','course_id'])['course_id'].transform('cumcount')+1
```

Returns:

```
   student_id course_id  Count
0      886652   SIM4207      1
1      886652   SIM4207      2
2     4484956   SSE3306      1
3     4484956   SSE3306      2
4     5843448   SSE3150      1
5      886652   SIM3150      1
```

EDIT:

Based on the expected output, it is easier to just groupby and `agg` by `count`:

```
print(df.groupby(['student_id','course_id']).agg({'course_id':'count'}).rename(columns={'course_id':'count'}).reset_index())
```

Which returns:

```
   student_id course_id  count
0      886652   SIM3150      1
1      886652   SIM4207      2
2     4484956   SSE3306      2
3     5843448   SSE3150      1
```